# Android runOnUiThread does not update layout elements

Tags: android

I have a problem in my Android application:
I'm trying to dynamically update text in TextView, but there is no change in UI. When I check in code (for example by displaying a Toast or in debugger) if the text has changed, it has, but the GUI is not updated.
Here is my code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNick"
    android:gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

```
public void changeNick(final String nick)  
{  
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  
    {  
        @Override  
        public void run()  
        {  
            View view = View.inflate(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.layout.activity_nick, null);  
            TextView textViewNick = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNick);  
            textViewNick.setText(nick);  
        }  
    });  
}
```

The `changeNick()` method is called from another class.
Does anyone know why is it so and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I found out that the `changeNick()` method is called before activity's `onCreate()`. I added a flag as a last instruction in `onCreate()` and I check it before calling `changeNick()`, but it didn't help and I still get IllegalStateException "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()".

**SOLVED**
The `changeNick()` method was called before activity's `onCreate()`, because I had two different instances of that activity. I was performing `changeNick() on the one that was not created yet, so I got NullPointerException.
Anyway, thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Have you tried inflating the view with the hosting activity's context? I see you're using the application context and that may not give you what you want.

Comment: Hi is it solved, Or still some issue left ?

Answer (score 0):

It's may be the same problem I faced when trying to update `TextView` on time tick, And doing like this worked,

```
public void changeNick(final String nick)  
{
   View view = View.inflate(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.layout.activity_nick, null);  
   TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNick);  
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {         
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                       
                        textView.setText(nick);
                    }
                });  
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to inflate the view every time you have to change the text.if you are using activity,initialise the view in the `onCreate()` method and then just update the view.You don't need to runOnUiThread since you are not updating from any background thread.You can directly update the view.The following should work for you.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
 TextView textView;
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
      textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNick);  
 }

public void changeNick(final String nick)  {  
    textView.setText(nick);  

}
```

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work, because in changeNick method this reference is null and I get NullPointerException. As i wrote, the changeNick method is called from another class, which is another thread, so runOnUiThread is needed.

Comment: How can the id of TextView be incorrect, if I use the same id as in xml layout file? As I wrote in edit, I found that my method is called to early by the other thread, before the `onCreate()` exectution is finished and I think it causes the problem. Now I'm looking for how to avoid it.

Comment: and how are you calling the method before oncreate().? from where are you calling that..? if show the entire code where the call is taking place,that would be more helpful

Answer (score -1):

simply use following line to set the text:

```
textView.setText(nick);
```

there is no need to change the text in `UI-Thread`